# can nowjs hold a stream that which is send by webrtc

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, nowjs-sockets

WebRTC is a free, open project that enables web browsers with Real-Time Communications (RTC) capabilities via simple Javascript APIs

and i can use this code to Capture my camera,this is the [demo](http://miernicki.com/cam.html)

```
if (navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) {

    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia('video', gotStream, noStream);

    var video = document.getElementById('monitor');
    var canvas = document.getElementById('photo');

    function gotStream(stream) {

        video.src = webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.onerror = function () {
            stream.stop();
            streamError();
        };
        document.getElementById('splash').hidden = true;
        document.getElementById('app').hidden = false;
    }

    function noStream() {
        document.getElementById('errorMessage').textContent = 'No camera available.';
    }

    function streamError() {
        document.getElementById('errorMessage').textContent = 'Camera error.';
    }

    function snapshot() {
        canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
        canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0);
    }

} else {
    document.getElementById('errorMessage').textContent = 'No native camera support available.';
}
```

and now , i want to send my camera stream to other people,

i have already create a chat room using nowjs,

so i want to know , Does the nowjs has method to hold the camera stream  and show on

the web-browser,

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The video stream need not be stored anywhere. It is transmitted from one client to the other through a [**Peer Connection**](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html#peerconnection). All you need to do is create such a connection, by transmitting the Signaling Messages (something like a 'Handshake') between the clients. The streaming is taken care by the API.